# ggplot transform y axis histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have this line of code:

```
ggplot(data=AB2, aes(AB2$logbm)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(-1.5, 2.5, by=((max(AB2$logbm)-min(AB2$logbm))/7)))
```

And I have problem in trying to transform the unit of y axis - first I need to log it, with:

```
scale_y_log10()
```

After that I want to divide all the values by `60`, then multiple by `1.25`. However with the above code, I dont seem to be able to adjust it with simply adding: `60*1.25` after the command.

Is there a way to tell `ggplot` to do it??

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, though not sure why you would want to, by using `..count..` in the `aes`

```
ggplot(AB2, aes(x = logbm)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count.. * 1.25 / 60))
```

NB no need to reference the data.frame in the aes.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define your own `trans` using the scales package. Normally:

```
scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

With transformation:

```
scale_y_continuous(trans = scales::trans_new("lognew", 
                                             transform = function(x){log10(x)*1.25/60},
                                             inverse = function(x){10^(x*60/1.25)})
                                             )
```